# How to webscrape multiple tables on same website

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, xlwings

I am trying to webscrape multiple tables from this website

this is my code

```
def scrape_ranking(url, sheet_name):
    with sync_playwright() as pw:
        browser = pw.chromium.launch()
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto(url, wait_until="networkidle")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content(), "html.parser")
        table = soup.select_one(".table_bd")
        print("done step 1")

        if table is None:
            print("Table not found.")
        else:
            df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
            print(df)
            with pd.ExcelWriter("jockeyclub.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=True, startrow = 70)

url_trainer = "https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/english/racing/Draw.aspx#race1.aspx"
scrape_ranking(url_trainer, "Race Card 1")
```

This code is able to print the table for Race Card 1. However, when I change the line to `df = pd.read_html(str(table))[1]` or `df = pd.read_html(str(table))[2]`, it isn't able to find any other tables in the website.

Is there a way to print all the tables on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case there seems no need to use a mix of modules. - Simply use `pandas.red_html()`, select the tables with `attrs` and iterate the list of `dataframes`:

```
import pandas as pd

url_trainer = "https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/english/racing/Draw.aspx#race1.aspx"

for table in pd.read_html(url_trainer, attrs={'class':'table_bd'}):
    print(table)
    # other tasks you have to perform on the dataframes
```

#### EDIT

Based on your provided url first part will work, but if you miss the `#race1...` in the end of the url, the site reacts slightly differently, providing a `user-agent` will fix this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url_trainer = "https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/english/racing/Draw.aspx"

list_of_df = pd.read_html(
                requests.get(
                    url_trainer, 
                    headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
                ).text, 
                attrs={'class':'table_bd'}
            )

for table in list_of_df:
    print(table)
```

Comment: Thanks! Followup question, is there a way to print all of these tables on to excel without overlapping each other?

```with pd.ExcelWriter("jockeyclub.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
    table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Draw", index=True, startrow = 1)```

this just prints race 10s results in a1

Comment: @NNBananas: To keep the post clean - This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus - Simply drop the link to the follow up question here, so everybody could take a look and help. Would be great, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77105979/tables-overlapping-each-other-when-webscraping