# How to avoid overlapping of scraped tables when creating excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape the tables from a website to excel:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url_trainer = "https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/english/racing/Draw.aspx"

list_of_df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url_trainer, headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}).text, attrs={'class':'table_bd'})

for table in list_of_df:
    print(table)

with pd.ExcelWriter("jockeyclub.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
    table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Draw", index=True, startrow = 1)
```

This just prints race 10s results in a1.

Is there a way to print all of these tables on to excel without overlapping each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this meets your expected output (just improve question in that way), but you could [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the list of `dataframes` after dropping the first column index level:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
```

You also could cleanup the summary row and the column with all `nan` values:

```
df = df.iloc[:-1,:].dropna(axis=1,how='all')
```

To be able to filter later on simply use the 0 level from multiindex to create a new column with the type of race:

```
df.columns.get_level_values(0)[0]
```

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url_trainer = "https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/english/racing/Draw.aspx"

list_of_df = []

for df in pd.read_html(requests.get(url_trainer, headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12; SM-A325F Build/SP1A.210812.016; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/115.0.5790.166 Mobile Safari/537.36'}).text, attrs={'class':'table_bd'}):
    race_type = df.columns.get_level_values(0)[0]
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
    df = df.iloc[:-1,:].dropna(axis=1,how='all')
    df['race_type'] = race_type
    list_of_df.append(df)

pd.concat(list_of_df, ignore_index=True).to_excel('jockeyclub.xlsx', index=False)
```

##### EDIT

In context of just appending an additional sheet to existing file with sheets as mentioned in the comments use the result of `pd.concat()` like:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("jockeyclub.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
    pd.concat(list_of_df, ignore_index=True).to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Draw", index=False)
```

##### Output

|  | Draw | Runners | Win | 2nd | 3rd | 4th | W% | Q% | P% | F% | race_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 86 | 12 | 5 | 9 | 7 | 14 | 20 | 30 | 38 | Race 1 1200m All weather track |
| 1 | 2 | 85 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 5 | 9 | 20 | 28 | 34 | Race 1 1200m All weather track |
| 2 | 3 | 86 | 6 | 11 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 20 | 30 | 38 | Race 1 1200m All weather track |
| 3 | 4 | 86 | 4 | 10 | 11 | 5 | 5 | 16 | 29 | 35 | Race 1 1200m All weather track |
| 4 | 5 | 86 | 11 | 10 | 7 | 9 | 13 | 24 | 33 | 43 | Race 1 1200m All weather track |
| 5 | 6 | 86 | 7 | 10 | 8 | 9 | 8 | 20 | 29 | 40 | Race 1 1200m All weather track |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 132 | 11 | 31 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 10 | 13 | 23 | Race 10 1400m Turf "B" Course |
| 133 | 12 | 30 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 3 | 7 | 10 | 27 | 37 | Race 10 1400m Turf "B" Course |
| 134 | 13 | 28 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 7 | 11 | 14 | 18 | Race 10 1400m Turf "B" Course |
| 135 | 14 | 26 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 15 | 23 | Race 10 1400m Turf "B" Course |

Comment: This code is able to print the whole table on excel. However, it deletes all the other sheets in the excel.

Comment: @NNBananas: That is why, because `to_excel()` create  a single sheet  file, simply use the last line in context with your `pd.ExcelWriter()` and it will append a the sheet. to your existing file with sheets.

Comment: so like this? ```pd.concat(list_of_df, ignore_index=True)pd.ExcelWriter('jockeyclub.xlsx', index=False)```Sorry, im a bit unfamiliar with this area of coding

Comment: @NNBananas: Added an edit, based on your question, check the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're open to suggestions for the format of the final spreadsheet `"Draw"` (*that belongs to an existing Excel file*). So, you'll find mine below. And by the way, your code throws a `FutureWarning` on [*2.1.0*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.1.0.html#other-deprecations), so I'll be using a different one to read the list of tables/DataFrames from the website :

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": (
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"
        "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    )
}

attributes = {"class": "table_bd"}

list_of_df = pd.read_html(url_trainer, storage_options=headers, attrs=attributes)
```

For the formatting [openpyxl](/questions/tagged/openpyxl) part, you can use something like below :

```
SN = "Draw2"
N = 3 # maximum number of tables per bloc
SR, SC = 2, 1 # starts of row/col (Excel's index)
HS, VS = 1, 2 # number of separators (empty row/col)

from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle, Font, Border, Alignment, Side, PatternFill

def ns(style_name):
    return NamedStyle(
    name=style_name,
    font=Font(name="Arial", size=14, bold=True),
    alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center", vertical="center"),
    border=Border(left=Side(style="thin"), right=Side(style='thin'),
                  top=Side(style='thin'), bottom=Side(style='thin')),
    fill=PatternFill(start_color="33c481", end_color="33c481", fill_type="solid")
)

with pd.ExcelWriter(
    "jockeyclub.xlsx", engine="openpyxl",
    mode="a", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
    for idx, df in enumerate(list_of_df):
        flat_df = df.droplevel(0, axis=1).dropna(how="all", axis=1)
        sr = (idx // N) * (max(df.shape[0] for df in list_of_df) + VS+1) + (SR-1)
        sc = (idx % N) * (len(flat_df.columns) + HS) + (SC-1)
        (flat_df.style.set_properties(**{"border":"1px solid"})
            .to_excel(writer, startrow=sr, startcol=sc, sheet_name=SN, index=False))
        ws = writer.sheets[SN]
        ws.cell(sr, sc+1).value = df.columns.levels[0][0]
        race_title = ws.cell(row=sr, column=sc+1)
        race_title.style = (ns("RaceTitleStyle") if "RaceTitleStyle"
                            not in writer.book.style_names else "RaceTitleStyle")
        ws.merge_cells(start_row=sr, start_column=sc+1,
                       end_row=sr, end_column=sc+len(df.columns)-1)
```

Output (*jockey.xlsx*) :

[image]